# Document the "recommendations" off-topic close reason

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, off-topic, close-reasons

Our close reason for questions that ask for recommendations states:

> Questions asking for **recommended external websites, tools, resources, and software** are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Recommendations for software are permitted on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to read their [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336) before posting there.

I have a user that is asking for documentation about where we decided that each of those recommendation categories is off-topic:

- External websites
- Tools
- Resources
- Software

I'd like to find the meta discussions relevant to each one, or if meta discussions don't exist, create documentation here.

If appropriate, should we modify the [help center](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to better match the wording of the off-topic reason?

Comment: I believe that software recommendations became off-topic from [Why so much tolerance for undifferentiated CMS recommendation questions?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/508/why-so-much-tolerance-for-undifferentiated-cms-recommendation-questions) and we decided not to make them on-topic again when I brought it up [Product recommendations and offsite resource questions, could they be made be on-topic again?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/product-recommendations-and-offsite-resource-questions-could-they-be-made-be-on)

Comment: I think hosting services were made off-topic with [We need to decide what we're doing with web hosting questions](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/584/we-need-to-decide-what-were-doing-with-web-hosting-questions)

Comment: We had a user request documentation a few years ago from which we created the current help center wording:  [Where is it mentioned that tool recommendation questions are off-topic?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/where-is-it-mentioned-that-tool-recommendation-questions-are-off-topic)

Comment: I'm struggling to find much documentation beyond that.

Comment: I've found some users requesting tools to help them with a problem. There are some tools that I use for the problems they've encountered and would gladly recommend them, but their questions get put on hold. I think site/software recommendations could be fine. It'll also bring in a lot of Google traffic for when people are searching for reviews of those products. If people abused recommendations then you could take action. Or perhaps setup a reputation requirement for these things. Just my thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that we edit the [help center](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to more closely match our off-topic close reason.   I'm proposing that we change the recommendations section to:

**Recommendations for sites and resources** — Questions that ask for recommendations of external websites, tools, resources, services, or software attract lots of self promotion and spam answers. In addition, answers to such questions quickly become out of date. Such questions are closed as off-topic.

Comment: I would suggest appending services in their too.

Comment: I don't disagree @SimonHayter, but isn't that covered by 'resources'?

Comment: Yes, technically the term resources do cover services  and forgive me if I come across as stereotyping but I would automatically assume that people whom their main language is not English would not know that resources also cover services.

Comment: I think adding services would be desirable.   I've edited that in to my suggestion.